# How to toggle table in column on button click using jQuery's toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

So, I want to be able to toggle a column in a table on a button click.

I looked into jQuery's toggle class function and figured I could give the th (table header) and td (cell in HTML table) the same class and then do a toggleClass on a button click.

Here's my table in my Dashboard.tsx file:

```
  <table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th class="lastname">LastName</th>
  <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {
   this.1stUserInfo.map((value, index, array) => {
     return(
       <tr>
          <td class="lastname">{value.LastName}</td>
       </tr>);
       }, this)
       }
       </tbody>
       </table>
```

Here's my button:

```
       <Button id="lastnamebutton" onClick={(e) => this.ShowLastName(e,this)}>Toggle Last Name</Button>
```

And here's my function in my JavaScript where I implement toggleClass

```
       public ShowLastName(event, caller) {
          $("#lastnamebutton").toggleClass(".lastname");
       }
```

What am I doing wrong and/or can you think of another way I can toggle a column in my table?

Comment: Sorry, its unclear what you want to achieve. You want to toggle your column (means hiding and showing your column) or toggleClass your column (means adding and removing class from your column) ?

Comment: Is this React? If so you shouldn't need jquery

Comment: I want to hide and show my column...yes this is React

Answer (score 1):

The `toggleClass()` is invoked on the incorrect elements. Instead of `#lastnamebutton`, it should be invoked on `.lastname`.

Here is an example (BTW, this case is not related with React):

```js
window.toggleColumn = function() {
  $('.yclass').toggleClass('hide');
};
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>X</th>
    <th class="yclass">Y</th>
    <th>Z</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>42</td>
      <td class="yclass">45</td>
      <td>46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>72</td>
      <td class="yclass">62</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="window.toggleColumn()">
Click
</button>
```